# How to delete or stop the cookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webforms

My website shows some cookies and I can't find the source/who generated. My client scan software complains about these cookies (not-secure), can any one please advice me how to fix this? [image]

Comment: I would look in global.asax

Comment: I looked into, there is no relevant code.

Comment: they are not secure, so you do not have issue on https pages, only the secure are pass from there

Comment: maybe some plugin from your browser add them